# Minimum number of moves algorithm in Java

Tags: java, libgdx, algorithm

I'm looking to implement the minimum number of moves algorithm for the java game I'm developing but I can't quite figure it out.

Here's an example picture:

[image]

There are also some specifications about this:

> The solution in the example above **is not unique**; other solutions would also be valid as long as the "final character layout (or the positioning of the characters in the nodes)" matches a certain condition (I don't think that's very relevant now so won't go into detail). Also, the nodes aren't actually moved, only it's content.
>
> Adjacent elements cannot be swapped (i.e. in the example above, on the starting side's first swap, 'E' couldn't be swapped with neither 'A' or 'B'; B could be swapped with any character but 'E' and so on.)
>
> The same character can be swapped as many times as one wishes. So, for example, 'B', in the starting side of the picture, could be swapped with 'D'
> in the first move (B and D trade places) and then 'B' could be swapped with, let's say, 'E' (so B and E trade places).

So how exactly should I approach this, in order to get the **minimum moves**? I don't need a full solution, but some pseudo-code or a couple of hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What constitutes a correct "solution"?  You say the "_final character layout (or the positioning of the characters in the nodes) matches a certain condition_"... but you'll have to explain that.  No one can give you a solution to a problem that isn't explained.

Comment: It sounds like you might want to use a search algorithm like A* - it's not only useful for path finding.

Comment: @Adam Hey, thanks for the tip, i'm going to take a look at it!

Comment: Yeah; for A*, instead of having the nodes be "locations" they are "game states" where the "destination" is a "win state". And the "arcs" are not "paths" but "moves". You have to compute _all_ the moves and game states that can be achieved from the current state and find the least "moves" to get to the "win" state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people have said in comments section, A* or (AStar) is a viable algorithm for this, and a good waypoint.

Here you have a generic AStar implementation in Java so you can start with something. 
Please, ask if you have any question.

```
import java.util.*;


public class AStar {


  public static class PriorityList extends LinkedList {

    public void add(Comparable object) {
      for (int i=0; i<size(); i++) {
        if (object.compareTo(get(i)) <= 0) {
          add(i, object);
          return;
        }
      }
      addLast(object);
    }
  }

  protected List constructPath(AStarNode node) {
    LinkedList path = new LinkedList();
    while (node.pathParent != null) {
      path.addFirst(node);
      node = node.pathParent;
    }
    return path;
  }

  public List findPath(AStarNode startNode, AStarNode goalNode) {

    PriorityList openList = new PriorityList();
    LinkedList closedList = new LinkedList();

    startNode.costFromStart = 0;
    startNode.estimatedCostToGoal =
      startNode.getEstimatedCost(goalNode);
    startNode.pathParent = null;
    openList.add(startNode);

    while (!openList.isEmpty()) {
      AStarNode node = (AStarNode)openList.removeFirst();
      if (node == goalNode) {
        // construct the path from start to goal
        return constructPath(goalNode);
      }

      List neighbors = node.getNeighbors();
      for (int i=0; i<neighbors.size(); i++) {
        AStarNode neighborNode =
          (AStarNode)neighbors.get(i);
        boolean isOpen = openList.contains(neighborNode);
        boolean isClosed =
          closedList.contains(neighborNode);
        float costFromStart = node.costFromStart +
          node.getCost(neighborNode);

        // check if the neighbor node has not been
        // traversed or if a shorter path to this
        // neighbor node is found.
        if ((!isOpen && !isClosed) ||
          costFromStart < neighborNode.costFromStart)
        {
          neighborNode.pathParent = node;
          neighborNode.costFromStart = costFromStart;
          neighborNode.estimatedCostToGoal =
            neighborNode.getEstimatedCost(goalNode);
          if (isClosed) {
            closedList.remove(neighborNode);
          }
          if (!isOpen) {
            openList.add(neighborNode);
          }
        }
      }
      closedList.add(node);
    }

    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for your answer! I ended up using BFS because i wasn't so sure about the heuristic to use in this case, but i'm definetly going to try it with A* now. Thanks!

Comment: BFS is also nice. You can try both and keep the one that fits your needs better.

Comment: Yeah, will do. Thank you very much for the help! :)